# Page-break on fixed elements

Tags: html, css

With CSS rule `page-break` in `@media print` it's easy to break content  when we are printing from browser. It works good for me except one thing: it's not working when element is fixed. Using `page-break-after: always` or `page-break-before: always` on fixed element didn't help, result is always the same - content simply overlaps that div. Is there any solution for this?

```
<div id="content">   
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

Content appears in content div and it is dynamical. 
CSS for footer:

```
@media screen{
  .footer{
    display:none;
  }
}

.footer{
  display:block;
  height:30px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Using this CSS footer appears on every page, but use of `page-break` in `.footer` class doesn't breaks the page?

Comment: Please show us more source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I figured is to give a content padding-bottom greater than the height of footer. In that case footer and content won't overlap.

```
.footer{
  display:block;
  height:30px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}

#content {
  ...
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: this can cause problems in responsive designs

Answer (score 1):

`break-after` is a more generic version of `page-break-after`.

Try it like `break-after:always` and let us know if it works.

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)